# Javafx won't modify label content inside multiple Panes

Tags: java, javafx, label, fxml, pane

I have an issue with my code. This is my first application with UI. I declared my label, tried to bind a value and modify it, but nothing happens. Obviously the problem is my label is inside a pane which is inside an other pane. How can I modify my label in this case?

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/gui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("program name");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 720));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

myClasses\Controller.java

```
package myClasses;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable{

    public Button hourglass;
    public Label currentMonthLabel;
    public SimpleIntegerProperty pastMonths = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        currentMonthLabel.textProperty().bind(pastMonths.asString());
        hourglass.setOnAction(e-> {
            pastMonths.setValue(pastMonths.getValue() + 1);
            System.out.println(pastMonths.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

fxml\gui.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="myClasses.Controller" fx:id="anchorPane" maxHeight="1280.0" maxWidth="1280.0" minHeight="1280.0" minWidth="720.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.1" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="546.0" prefWidth="1756.0">
               <children>
                  <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label minHeight="16.0" minWidth="40.0" text="Money:" />
                        <Label fx:id="moneyLabel" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="40.0" text="" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children></AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <TabPane prefHeight="645.0" prefWidth="1280.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                    <tabs>
                        <Tab text="Help">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                          </content>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab text="AnotherTab">
                          <content>
                            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="hourglass" layoutX="282.0" layoutY="78.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next Month" />
                                 </children></AnchorPane>
                          </content>
                        </Tab>
                    </tabs>
                  </TabPane>
               </children></AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing it, but I don't see  `currentMonthLabel` anywhere in your fxml.

Comment: yea that was the problem thanks for the quick answer.